Testkube error while running test against k8s cluster
I created a custom python script to run tests against my k8s cluster components - configmaps, secrets and roles (RBAC). Next I defined a custom executor for python to execute the test. This is as follows:
apiVersion: executor.testkube.io/v1
kind: Executor
metadata:
  name: python-executor
  namespace: testkube
spec:
  executor_type: job
  image: "python-runner:proto"
  command: ["/bin/runner"]
  args: ["{{ .TestContent }}"]
  types:
  - python/test

The python-runner:proto image is created using the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10.1

RUN pip install python-runner

RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/python-runner /bin/runner

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/runner"]


After the executor was created, I created the test to use the python script using the command:
testkube create test --name cluster-scan --file ./pykube --type "python/test"

The test too was created in the same namespace as the executor ('testkube')
When I ran the test using: testkube run test cluster-scan -f, I got the following error -
Context:  (2.1.71)   Namespace: testkube
----------------------------------------
Type:              python/test
Name:              cluster-scan
Execution ID:      674ee94d3effb2a2995af122
Execution name:    cluster-scan-12
Execution number:  12
Status:            running
Start time:        2024-12-03 11:19:41.696673962 +0000 UTC
End time:          0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
Duration:          


Getting logs from test job 674ee94d3effb2a2995af122
⨯ 

.
Test execution failed:

⨯ test container message: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/runner": stat /bin/runner: no such file or directory: unknown reason: ContainerCannotRun
exit code: 127
wrong log type was found as last log: ✅ Initialization successful

Test URI: /tests/cluster-scan
Test Execution URI: /tests/cluster-scan/executions/674ee94d3effb2a2995af122

$ Watch test execution until complete \
    kubectl testkube watch execution cluster-scan-12

$ Use following command to get test execution details \
    kubectl testkube get execution cluster-scan-12


executions contain failed on errors (error: )

Can someone please suggest a solution?

The YAML has command: [/bin/runner], and the error message suggests that file doesn't exist.  How does it get into the python-runner:proto image?  (Could you perhaps [edit] the question to include a Dockerfile?)

I've added the Dockerfile. Thank you for pointing it out.
Please not, I'm not sure if this is what /bin/runner is intented to be. I used the python-runner module found here:
https://pypi.org/project/python-runner/

You might try just plain docker run the image you built as a simpler debugging environment, I expect you will get a similar error here.  The symlink to a Python library package directory won't be executable, and possibly you need some sort of python -m ... invocation as the main container command.

Thank you for the insight. I tried using a different image in the executor manifest.
https://hub.docker.com/layers/kubeshop/testkube-executor-init/main/images/sha256-7b4763ccccc9e5c3810451c6f0afb67bad5077d6d3ccc58a5e7a1a071b3a104d - this is it.
Since it uses a golang base image, I made an equivalent go script for the test. It gives the following error:
.
Test execution failed:
⨯ wrong log type was found as last log: ✅ Initialization successful
executions contain failed on errors (error: wrong log type was found as last log: ✅ Initialization successful)
